# Div content container cuts off before end of content?

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

So have a div that basically the main content of a page, but it doesnt extend to the bottom of the content that is inside it. I have tried many different things, but not sure if i have the wrong combination of css properties to make it display right. Someone please offer an explanation. Below is html and css.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
height:100%;
position:relative;
background:url("../image/la_woodlands.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

.main_content_wrapper{
position:relative;
}

.content_container{
position:relative;
left:50%;
top:0;
margin-left:-480px;
width:920px;
padding:30px 20px;
height:100%;
display:block;
background:rgba(41,41,41,.8);
}

.content_section_header{
position:relative;
top:20px;
}



    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main_content_wrapper">
 <div class="content_container">


  <h1 class="align_center"></h1>

  <div class="content_section_header">
  <h1 class="align_center times">Catalog</h1>
  <div class="catalog_navigation">
  <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
  <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
   <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
    <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
     <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
      <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
       <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
        <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
         <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
          <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
           <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
            <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
             <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>
              <h1>fjebgrewgre</h1>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not stretching? http://jsfiddle.net/tjfNU/

Comment: The main content container, with the white background, stops at a certain height, so when I have enough content, it doesn't stretch the container enough to have the white background behind my content. In other words it won't stretch vertically

Comment: Please update your HTML to show us how the content won't "stretch".  I have tried a couple of things here, http://jsfiddle.net/nZcsE/1/, but everything looks fine.

Comment: Ive just copied and pasted the code i posted into a raw html file, and it still wont stretch. Try changing the css background rgb to (41,41,41) and maybe you will see. Also, i had about 14 <h1> tags within the content, just to add some dummy content, and around the 6th heading the background stopped. Something on my end is wrong and I really don't know what else to do to help. Im sorry for the confusion but this is the only way i can think to explain it, its almost as if the content containe rhas a fixed height, and my headings are flowing outside of the bottom of it

Comment: @Lowkase I have updated the html i have tested in my broswer, and it does NOT work. The html and css i used is updated in the question! Just copy and paste it over to your text editor and run it in a broswer

Answer (score 0):

The background does fit the content?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use `float` `.content_container` so that if ever you add content the height of `.content_container` will automatically adjust

```
.content_container{
float:left;
position:relative;
left:50%;
top:0;
margin-left:-480px;
width:920px;
padding:30px 20px;
display:block;
background:rgba(255,255,255,.9) no-repeat;
}
```

here sample [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/tjfNU/3/) is this what you want to achieve correct me if i am wrong

*note: add more `h1` tag to show the effect*

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code:

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
}

.content_container {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwvMK/)

I've also changed:

```
.content_container {
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    margin-left:-480px;
}
```

to:

```
.content_container {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

because it's cleaner code.